# Mailgun not sending mail on my live application

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to make mailgun work for my live site. Everything with the dns is set up correctly. This is what I have in the env file. Is it something besides the `env fil`e that I've forgotten? Guzzle is installed.

```
MAIL_MAILER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@mg.mydomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@mydomain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=mg.mydomain.com
MAILGUN_SECRET=thefirstapikeyfrommailgun

MAILGUN_ENDPOINT=
```

Comment: Check your log for errors.

Comment: I found this unable to parse URI